# drawing and animating a page of a book on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, css-transitions

I am trying create a div inside of a canvas.
I'd like to have the div behaving like in this pic: http://i40.tinypic.com/10fxaxi.png. The div should transition from step1 to step5 like described on the image.

It's like having a page of a book fliping on this angle, view and perspective.
can someone help me about it? it should be just Html5, css3 and any JS pr Jquery.
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.turnjs.com/ Just googled it :p

Comment: i already looked at this one. they don't have the perspective or view angle that i'm looking for. :(

Comment: Just use something like 'transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(20deg)' on the whole turnjs shebang...seems to do the trick ;)

Comment: can you describe the image, instead of using a link that right now is a dead link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do your page flip with canvas context's transforms.

The scaling can be done with context.scale(scaleX,scaleY).

The rotation can be done with context.rotate(radianAngle).

Skewing does not have a dedicated context command but can be done with context.transform(1, skewY, skewX, 1, 0, 0);

You will also need context.translate which sets the origin point of all scaling, rotating and skewing operations: context.translate(X,Y).

Give this a try and come back with your code if you have questions.

Good luck with your project!